# Intel HAXM not getting installed in vmware Mac Mojave , VT-X enabled

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, haxm

I have looked through all solutions for 2 days now. My problem is im trying to run AVD from android studio , when I click play button for Nexus 5X in avd manager I get following error - intel HAXM is required to runm this AVD. /dev/kvm not found.I tried installing Intel HAXM directly from intel website , the installation went alright but the problem persisted. Please need help. Thanks

Comment: I realize this is not a solution, but rather my experience. I have never been able to get an Android emulator to run on Mac OS. I recommend you use a physical device for testing instead. You can also try Genymotion's emulators, which in my opinion are better than the native AVD, but it is a commercial product.

Comment: ok thanks for the tip